# To be able to change file permission in directory?

Tags: php, file-upload, permissions

I've got such a directory:

```
uploads/
add1
add2
add3

thumbs/
image1
image2
image3
```

The problem is adeed files under uploads folder or images under thumbs do not exist! If the user creates an add add file comes down under uploads and as an image uploaded an image comes down under thumbs.

My problem: added files and images get 644 file permission as default and I can NOT view the images!

My question: How can I make that added files get file permission 755 by default?

What I did so far:

- I have asked my hosting comp. and they couldn't figure it out.
- I have tried `chmod("/uploads/thumbs", 0755);` I put that just after `mysql_connect`...

Comment: You will **never** want to make a user-uploaded file `755`. `755` means that the files will be able to be executed. `644` should be enough.

Comment: Your problem is probably somewhere else than in privileges, 644 (`-rw-r--r--`) contains read rights for everyone.

Comment: Read ['How to set file permissions - numeric mode'](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/filepermissions.html#hownum) to understand what `0755` and `0644` actually means.

Comment: If 644 was enough what was my problem then? why cant I view images? While I was working on my computer It was all fine..why not online? Where should I look then? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to recursively change the folder and existing files permissions to 644. I found this and made some adaptions. Would this one work?

```
exec ("find /uploads/thumbs -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} +");
```

In case you are doing something like `crop($file,$destination);` change the permission after writing the file:

```
chmod($file, 0644)
```